# Change a non-striped LVM LV into a striped LV

Tags: linux, lvm, raid

I currently have several logical volumes (LVs) on a volume group (VG). This VG is hosted on a single physical volume (PV). I have a spare drive which I can use to shuffle data around on.

I also now have a new drive which matches my original PV drive. I would like to move the existing LVs around and end up with the LVs being striped across the two PVs. Is this possible? How do you do it?

Comment: Are you aware that data striped over multiple disks is completely lost if a single drive fails?

Comment: It's a completely valid question, but just as SvenW said, there's no difference between RAID0 and LVM striping.

Comment: I would assume people would run this over RAID-1 arrays, effectively making this a RAID-10 setup.

Comment: Only if the spare drive can hold _all_ of the data in the entire VG at once.

Answer (score 6):

It seems this is not possible from the commandline. `striping` is quite different from the default `linear` allocation scheme. So while you can grow a file system across multiple physical volumes (`PV`), you do not get the "load balancing" advantages of striping.

To grow the filesystem, you would do something like this:

```
pvcreate /dev/mapper/md2_crypt
vgextend crypto /dev/mapper/md2_crypt
umount /dev/mapper/crypto-srv
fsck.ext4 -C0 -f /dev/mapper/crypto-srv
lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/crypto-srv
resize2fs /dev/mapper/crypto-srv
mount /srv
```

In the above example, `md2_crypt` is a crypto volume on top of a RAID-1 array, but it could be any device. `crypto` is the volume group (`VG`) and `crypto-srv` is the logical volume that holds the filesystem mounted on `/srv`.

> Reminder: you should really use at least a RAID-1 array because if a PV fails in a `linear` logical volume (`LV`), you can loose all the data.

This will *not* make the `/srv` partition striped across the PVs. This is because [there are no userland tools to support `linear` to `striped` conversions](http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2008-December/msg00096.html). Logically, this would be in the `lvconvert` command, but that only supports moving from `linear` to `mirror` mode and back, for example. And with all the new development going into [BTRFS](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org), I would be surprised if this ever documented.

One thing you *can* do however, is have the *new* data on the drive be striped. That is rather tricky, but it can be done. Let's assume we want to stripe `crypto-tmp`, the LV for `/tmp`. We first need to free up space for the stripes in the first PV:

```
pvmove -n crypto/tmp /dev/mapper/md1_crypt
```

This will reallocate the LV across the PVs, in my case it moved it all to the second PV:

```
root@foo:~# pvs --segments -o+lv_name,seg_start_pe,segtype
  PV                    VG     Fmt  Attr PSize PFree  Start SSize  LV   Start Type
  /dev/mapper/md1_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  2.73t 10.00g     0   2384 root     0 linear
  /dev/mapper/md1_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  2.73t 10.00g  2384    256 swap     0 linear
  /dev/mapper/md1_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  2.73t 10.00g  2640   2560          0 free
  /dev/mapper/md1_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  2.73t 10.00g  5200 709901 srv      0 linear
  /dev/mapper/md2_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  1.82t  1.81t     0   2560 tmp      0 linear
  /dev/mapper/md2_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  1.82t  1.81t  2560 474077          0 free
```

Now you can grow the filesystem (say we double its size) and tell LVM to stripe the new data:

```
root@foo:~# lvresize -i 2 -l 5120 /dev/crypto/tmp
  Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB
  Extending logical volume tmp to 20.00 GiB
  Logical volume tmp successfully resized
```

Now the new data for `/tmp` is striped across the two PVs:

```
root@foo:~# pvs --segments -o+lv_name,seg_start_pe,segtype
  PV                    VG     Fmt  Attr PSize PFree Start SSize  LV   Start Type
  /dev/mapper/md1_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  2.73t 5.00g     0   2384 root     0 linear
  /dev/mapper/md1_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  2.73t 5.00g  2384    256 swap     0 linear
  /dev/mapper/md1_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  2.73t 5.00g  2640   1280 tmp   2560 striped
  /dev/mapper/md1_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  2.73t 5.00g  3920   1280          0 free
  /dev/mapper/md1_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  2.73t 5.00g  5200 709901 srv      0 linear
  /dev/mapper/md2_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  1.82t 1.80t     0   2560 tmp      0 linear
  /dev/mapper/md2_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  1.82t 1.80t  2560   1280 tmp   2560 striped
  /dev/mapper/md2_crypt crypto lvm2 a--  1.82t 1.80t  3840 472797          0 free
```

But the original data is still in `linear` mode. It may be possible to *move* the filesystem to the striped extents, but consider that an exercise to the reader at this point. :)

See also [Growing a LVM volume with striping](https://serverfault.com/questions/271059/growing-a-lvm-volume-with-striping) and [Redhat LVM changing stripes?](https://serverfault.com/questions/293157/redhat-lvm-changing-stripes?rq=1).

Also note that the reverse (converting `striped` to `linear`) is possible, however: [Is it possible to convert striped logical volume to linear logical volume?](https://serverfault.com/questions/229812/is-it-possible-to-convert-striped-logical-volume-to-linear-logical-volume?rq=1).